# Move feature branch to another branch

Tags: git

We have a feature branch `features/foo` created off `master` that has not yet been merged.

Recently we created a new `dev` branch so that `master` only contains releases.

I therefore need to move `features/foo` onto `dev`.

Do I need to create a new branch from `dev` for the feature and then push to that or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `git rebase`:

```
git checkout features/foo
git rebase dev
```

There is more documentation about the `rebase` command [here](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html).

Comment: Doesn't this mean the branch is still off of `master`?

Comment: No, because you just rebased it on `dev`.  The beauty of git is, of course, that you can just make a copy of your repository and try this out and see if does what you want.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Any problems doing this with a public branch? I thought rebasing public branches was discouraged?

Comment: I think that for what you're doing -- moving a branch from one parent to another -- just about any solution is going to require some work on the part of people who already have it checked out.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the changes that you checked into `features/foo` to be applied to `dev` and not any other changes that were checked into `master` between the time `dev` got branched off and your changes, you'd want to use

```
git checkout features/foo
git rebase --onto dev master
```

Doing a straight `git rebase [target-branch]` may include more changes than you want, depending on your exact branch history. Source: https://makandracards.com/makandra/10173-git-how-to-rebase-your-feature-branch-from-one-branch-to-another